# How can I get type information as a string?

Tags: python

I have an object 'something'. Calling it returns (for example):

`<CTE 'WITH' at 0x1853B0A2888>`

What is the best way to get this output (or the *CTE 'WITH'* part)  as a string? The closest I got was by using

`str(something.__repr__)`

which returns

`"<bound method Token.__repr__ of <CTE 'WITH' at 0x1853B0A2888>>"`

which I can then trim/clean up to get what I want. But I'd like to hear about better ways to go about this.

(Sorry for the vague title, I don't know the right words for phrasing it better.)

Comment: `__repr__` is a method, so you could call it...

Answer (score 1):

If we're speaking about figuring our class name of an object as a string in Python, then I can suggest you to try this:

```
>>> a = "adsf"
>>> a.__class__.__name__
'str'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you the builtin function `id()` on your object.

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
         self.a = 5

def main():
    object = A()
    print(object)
    print(id(object))
```

will print `<__main__.A instance at 0x02968558>` in the first `print()` and `43418968` in the second. 43418968 is just 0x02968558 converted to base 10